# Moderator variable in meta-regression analysis and treatment effect heterogeneity

Tags: interaction, meta-regression, heterogeneity

Meta-regression may reveal that variable A explains heterogeneity in pooled treatment effect of X.

In a clinical trial I can investigate whether there is interaction between treatment allocation and variable A regarding treatment effect X.

These are fundamentally different concepts.

But if I found a significant moderator in a meta-regression analysis would it be reasonable to investigate its interaction effect in further study? Are these concepts absolutely different and independent of each other?